# Wordpress the_date(); How to change language

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have function:

```html
<p class="card-text">
<small class="text-muted font-12">
<?php echo the_date();?>
</small>
</p>
```

And i get written by every post example:
5 moths ago
2 weeks ago
...
How can i change EN language words to different language by using only code, without plughins or else.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the_date is a wordpress function that basically displays/retrieves the date the current post was written.

I believe you should be able to do this from the Wordpress backend admin by going to Settings > Site Language here:

[image]

If you wanted to only change the language specific to that date, you could try to do a filter hook for the add_date function. A quick sample should be:

```
add_filter('the_time', 'change_date_format');

function change_date_format(){
  //change date language here
  return get_the_time('Y');
}
```

reference for the hook: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_time/. You will need to add this filter to your theme's functions.php file.